# My system is broken I guess -- issues with libqt4-test

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, sudo, dependencies

So here's the problem, every time I try to install a package, I receive an error that says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt4-test : Breaks: libqt4-test:i386 (!= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
 libqt4-test:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3 is to be installed
                    Breaks: libqt4-test (!= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then, when I call `sudo apt-get -f install`, I receive this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libpgm-5.1-0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libqt4-test:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libqt4-test:i386
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/61.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: error processing libqt4-test:i386 (--configure):
 libqt4-test:i386 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 cannot be configured because libqt4-test:amd64 is in a different version (4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3)
dpkg: error processing libqt4-test (--configure):
 libqt4-test:amd64 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3 cannot be configured because libqt4-test:i386 is in a different version (4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2)
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqt4-test:i386
 libqt4-test
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I might find my way out of this dilemma?

Comment: Did you add a ppa to the Software sources? It might be breaking your apt system. Disable ppa's one by one starting from the last one added running `sudo apt-get update` after each change.

Comment: @ToDo only Chrome and Google Talk... and http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu... Could that be it ? UPDATE: Tried disabling those, didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like multi-arch skew. Apt can see version `4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2` for `i386` and `4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3` for `amd64`, but it needs the same version for both architectures.

Maybe you updated at a really bad time, when this package had built for `amd64` but not `i836` yet?

`4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3` has built for both of them, so so you should be able to do an `apt-get update` followed by an `apt-get -f install`.

Solution:
`dpkg --force-depends --remove libqt4-test libqt4-test:i386` to remove both of them, then re-install them with `apt-get -f install libqt4-test libqt4-test:i386`

Comment: I have tried that, still get a similar message than the second snipped I posted.

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy libqt4-test libqt4-test:i386`?

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1405558/

Comment: `apt-get -f install libqt4-test:i386=4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3` ?

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1407867/

Comment: `dpkg --force-depends --remove libqt4-test libqt4-test:i386`, then apt-get install them?